I am getting some typescript error in my Class component when exporting in HOC component
Below is my HomePage Class Component. I am getting some typescript error.
   import * as React from "react";
    import { Dispatch, AnyAction } from 'redux';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual";
    import "./HomePage.scss";
    import "../assets/styles.scss";
    import { resourceTypeEnum } from '../config/constants';
    import ResourceStocks from "./ResourceStocks";
    import SimcardStocks from "./SimcardStocks";
    import MsisdnStocks from "./MsisdnStocks";
    import DeviceStocks from './DeviceStocks';
    import { ConsulState } from "../consul/consul.types";
    import { consulInit } from "../consul/consul.data";
    import { HomePageActions, resourceStocksDataType, stocksFilterValuesType, lifecycleStatusesTypes, stocksDetailsTypes, resourceFilterValuesTypes, searchableFieldValuesTypes } from './HomePage.actions';
    import { AppState } from '../store';
    const classnames = require("classnames");
    
    interface HomePageStateProps {
        activeResourceType?: string;
    }
    
    interface HomePageProps {
        resourceStocks: resourceStocksDataType,
        stocksFilterValues: stocksFilterValuesType,
        lifecycleStatuses: lifecycleStatusesTypes,
        stocksDetails: stocksDetailsTypes;
        resourceFilterValues: resourceFilterValuesTypes;
        searchableFieldFilterValues: searchableFieldValuesTypes;
        isLoading: boolean;
        match: {
            params: {
                resourceType: string,
                stockId: string
            }
        };
        history: RouteComponentProps["history"];
        consulDetails: ConsulState
    }
    interface HomePageActionProps {
        actions: {
            getResourceStocks: (resourceType: string, stockID: string, stockName: string, SKU: string, currentPage: string) => void;
            getStocksFilterValues: (resourceType: string) => void,
            getLifecycleStatus: (resourceType: string) => void,
            getResourceFilterValues: (resourceType: string, stockID: string) => void,
            getSearchableFieldVFilterValues: (resourceType: string) => void,
        }
    }
    
    type Props = HomePageStateProps & HomePageActionProps & HomePageProps;
    class HomePage extends React.Component<Props, HomePageStateProps> {
        constructor(props: Props, context: any) {
            super(props, context);
            this.state = {
                activeResourceType: this.props.match && this.props.match.params && this.props.match.params.resourceType ? this.props.match.params.resourceType : 'sim-cards',
            };
        }
    
        handleOnCickResourceType = (resourceType: string) => {
            this.setState({
                activeResourceType: resourceType,
            });
            this.props.history && this.props.history.push(`/home/${resourceType}`)
            
        };
    
        static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: Props, prevState: HomePageStateProps) {
            const { match : { params : { resourceType } } = { params : { resourceType: resourceTypeEnum.SIM_CARDS }} } = nextProps;
            if (!isEqual(resourceType, prevState.activeResourceType)) {
                return { ...prevState, activeResourceType:  resourceType }
            }
        }
    
        getStocksAndFilterValues = (resourceType: string) => {
            this.props.actions.getResourceStocks(resourceType,'All', 'All', 'All', '');
            this.props.actions.getStocksFilterValues(resourceType);
        }
    
        getStockDetailsPageData = (resourceType: string, stockId: string) => {
            this.props.actions.getLifecycleStatus(resourceType);
            this.props.actions.getResourceFilterValues(resourceType, stockId);
            this.props.actions.getSearchableFieldVFilterValues(resourceType);
        }
        
        fetchResourceStocks = () => {
            this.props.actions.getResourceStocks(this.state.activeResourceType,'All', 'All', 'All', '')
        }
        render() {
            const { consulDetails: { details } = { details: consulInit }, match: { params : { stockId }} = { params: { stockId: ""}} } = this.props;
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div className="w-app-body" id="w-app-body">
                        <nav className="w-nav-secondary">
                            <ul>
                                {
                                    details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableSimCards && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableSimCards &&
                                    <li
                                        className={classnames({
                                            active:
                                                resourceTypeEnum.SIM_CARDS === this.state.activeResourceType,
                                        })}
                                    >
                                        <a
                                            href="javascript:;"
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                this.handleOnCickResourceType(
                                                    resourceTypeEnum.SIM_CARDS
                                                )
                                            }
                                            id='sim-cards-tab-in-resource-tab'
                                        >
                                            SIM Cards
                                    </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                                {
                                    details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableMsisdns && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableMsisdns &&
                                    <li
                                        className={classnames({
                                            active:
                                                resourceTypeEnum.MSISDNS === this.state.activeResourceType,
                                        })}
                                    >
                                        <a
                                            href="javascript:;"
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                this.handleOnCickResourceType(
                                                    resourceTypeEnum.MSISDNS
                                                )
                                            }
                                            id='Msisdns-tab-in-resource-tab'
                                        >
                                            MSISDNs
                                    </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                                {
                                    details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableDevices && details.resourceStockAndSearchConfig.enableDevices && 
                                    <li
                                        className={classnames({
                                            active:
                                                resourceTypeEnum.DEVICES === this.state.activeResourceType,
                                        })}
                                    >
                                        <a
                                            href="javascript:;"
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                this.handleOnCickResourceType(
                                                    resourceTypeEnum.DEVICES
                                                )
                                            }
                                            id='Devices-tab-in-resource-tab'
                                        >
                                            Devices
                                    </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        {/* <ResourceStocks
                            getStocksAndFilterValues={(resourceType: string) => this.getStocksAndFilterValues(resourceType)}
    
                            getStockDetailsPageData={(resourceType: string, stockId: string) => this.getStockDetailsPageData(resourceType, stockId)}
                            stockIdIfAvailable={this.props.match.params.stockId}
                            stockDetailsIfAvailable={this.props.selectedStockDetails}
                            setSelectedStockDetails={(stockDetails: object) => this.props.actions.setSelectedStockDetails(stockDetails)}
                            history={this.props.history}
    
    
                            resourceStocks={this.props.resourceStocks}
                            stocksFilterValues={this.props.stocksFilterValues}
                            lifecycleStatuses={this.props.lifecycleStatuses}
                            resourceFilterValues={this.props.resourceFilterValues}
                            searchableFieldFilterValues={this.props.searchableFieldFilterValues}
    
    
                            activeResourceType={this.state.activeResourceType}
                            stocksDetails={this.props.stocksDetails}
                            fetchResourceStocks={this.fetchResourceStocks}
    
                        /> */}
                        {(() => {
                            switch (this.state.activeResourceType) {
                                case resourceTypeEnum.SIM_CARDS:
                                    return <SimcardStocks 
                                        getStocksAndFilterValues = {(resourceType: string) => this.getStocksAndFilterValues(resourceType)}
                                        getStockDetailsPageData = {(resourceType: string, stockId: string) => this.getStockDetailsPageData(resourceType, stockId)}
                                        stockIdIfAvailable = {stockId}
                                        history = {this.props.history}
                                        resourceStocks = {this.props.resourceStocks}
                                        stocksFilterValues = {this.props.stocksFilterValues}
                                        lifecycleStatuses = {this.props.lifecycleStatuses}
                                        resourceFilterValues =  {this.props.resourceFilterValues}
                                        searchableFieldFilterValues = {this.props.searchableFieldFilterValues}
                                        activeResourceType = {this.state.activeResourceType}
                                        stocksDetails = {this.props.stocksDetails}
                                        fetchResourceStocks = {this.fetchResourceStocks}
                                    />;
                                case resourceTypeEnum.MSISDNS:
                                    return <MsisdnStocks 
                                        getStocksAndFilterValues = {(resourceType: string) => this.getStocksAndFilterValues(resourceType)}
                                        getStockDetailsPageData = {(resourceType: string, stockId: string) => this.getStockDetailsPageData(resourceType, stockId)}
                                        stockIdIfAvailable = {stockId}
                                        history = {this.props.history}
                                        resourceStocks = {this.props.resourceStocks}
                                        stocksFilterValues = {this.props.stocksFilterValues}
                                        lifecycleStatuses = {this.props.lifecycleStatuses}
                                        activeResourceType = {this.state.activeResourceType}
                                        stocksDetails = {this.props.stocksDetails}
                                        resourceFilterValues =  {this.props.resourceFilterValues}
                                        searchableFieldFilterValues = {this.props.searchableFieldFilterValues}
                                        fetchResourceStocks = {this.fetchResourceStocks}
                                    />;
                                case resourceTypeEnum.DEVICES:
                                    return <DeviceStocks 
                                        getStocksAndFilterValues = {(resourceType: string) => this.getStocksAndFilterValues(resourceType)}
                                        getStockDetailsPageData = {(resourceType: string, stockId: string) => this.getStockDetailsPageData(resourceType, stockId)}
                                        stockIdIfAvailable = {stockId}
                                        history = {this.props.history}
                                        resourceStocks = {this.props.resourceStocks}
                                        stocksFilterValues = {this.props.stocksFilterValues}
                                        lifecycleStatuses = {this.props.lifecycleStatuses}
                                        activeResourceType = {this.state.activeResourceType}
                                        stocksDetails = {this.props.stocksDetails}
                                        resourceFilterValues =  {this.props.resourceFilterValues}
                                        searchableFieldFilterValues = {this.props.searchableFieldFilterValues}
                                        fetchResourceStocks = {this.fetchResourceStocks}
                                    />;
                            }
                        })()}
                        <div className={classnames({"overlay": true, "show-spinner": !this.props.isLoading})}>
                            <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-4x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
    
    const mapsStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
        return {
            resourceStocks: state.homePage.resourceStocks,
            stocksFilterValues: state.homePage.stocksFilterValues,
            lifecycleStatuses: state.homePage.lifecycleStatuses,
            stocksDetails: state.homePage.stocksDetails,
            resourceFilterValues: state.homePage.resourceFilterValues,
            searchableFieldFilterValues: state.homePage.searchableFieldFilterValues,
            isLoading: state.homePage.isLoading,
            consulDetails: state.consul,
        };
    }
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>): HomePageActionProps => {
        return {
            actions: {
                getResourceStocks: (resourceType: string, stockID: string, stockName: string, SKU: string, currentPage: string) => {
                    dispatch(HomePageActions.getResourceStocks(resourceType, stockID, stockName, SKU, currentPage))
                },
                getStocksFilterValues: (resourceType: string) => {
                    dispatch(HomePageActions.getStockFilterValues(resourceType));
                },
                getLifecycleStatus: (resourceType: string) => {
                    dispatch(HomePageActions.getLifecycleStatus(resourceType))
                },
                getResourceFilterValues: (resourceType: string, stockID: string) => {
                    dispatch(HomePageActions.getResourceFilterValues(resourceType, stockID))
                },
                getSearchableFieldVFilterValues: (resourceType: string) => {
                    dispatch(HomePageActions.getSearchableFieldVFilterValues(resourceType))
                },
            },
        };
    };
    
    export default connect(mapsStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage)

export default connect(mapsStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage)
i am getting error here

Argument of type 'typeof HomePage' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'ComponentType'.   Type 'typeof HomePage' is not
assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
The types returned by 'getDerivedStateFromProps(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type '{ activeResourceType: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial |

any suggestion on how to fix this error and why i am getting this error.

In the getDerivedStateFromProps() method, there is a case that leads to confusion:

when isEqual(resourceType, prevState.activeResourceType) is true, the function will not return anything (ie undefind) this leads to confusion that typescript does not allow.

Solution:
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: Props, prevState: HomePageStateProps) {
    const resourceType = nextProps.match?.params?.resourceType || resourceTypeEnum.SIM_CARDS;
    if (!isEqual(resourceType, prevState.activeResourceType)) {
        return {
            activeResourceType: resourceType
        };
    }
    return null; //<- changed here
}

